# How to retain data in an Activity, when its in pause state

Tags: java, android, performance, android-layout

When user clicks on Login button, `PaymentDetials` Activity launches. It does a lot of processing, with that it also gets total items in cart.

I save count of total_items in an `Static` variable

User clicks on `Payment_form`, he enters his payment details, clicks `OK`, and we are back on the same activity, `PaymentDetails`

Everything is working fine with `static` variable, but this approach may cause `memory leak`.

So i decided to create a local variable in my activity, but the local variable value becomes `0`, after user comes to `Payment_details` from `PaymentForm` activity.

```
     int orderLineItems=0;

     onCreate(){
     orderLineItems+=1;
     }
```

Comment: why don't you use sharedpreference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Application` or `SharedPreferences` to store your data. If you need to store your data into `SharedPreferences` you can use my library for easy to use:

```
SharedPreferencesManager.getInstance().putValue("testData", testGun); // save object
Gun gun = SharedPreferencesManager.getInstance().getValue("testData", Gun.class); // get value
```

you can check this [Github link](https://github.com/kingfisherphuoc/EasySharedPreference) for more detail.